# r function argument not evaluated in expected manner

Tags: r, environment

This one is tricky.
We use

```
as.environment(-1)
```

to get the enclosing environment of a function.
If you run this in global env, you will get error; easy to understand, there is no function, so no place to hold the production of the function.

Here I made a function, using it as an default argument.

```
f = function(x =  as.environment(-1)){
  ls.str(x)
}
```

if you run `f(),f(as.environment(-1)),f(a<-as.environment(-1))`
You didn't get any error.

The first two could get understand because the lazy evaluation, evaluate when used, so when the as.environment(-1) get called, it is already inside the loading/temporary/executing environment of
the function, so the command is valid.

The third one, which I believe the evaluation before the real call, since it get var a in global environment being binding; how every if it is evaluated in global, there is no enclosing env, Should throw error. If it is evaluated inside the function, how come the var a in global environment get created/modified?

So is that the evaluation happens in function's running environment but the binding happened in global environment? That could be an explanation while the logic is weird.

Comment: While I am not sure how to solve your specific issue, what are you trying to achieve with passing the whole parent environment along? This question might be a case of the XY-Problem.

Comment: Have you read the relevant section of the R Language Definition? https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation

Comment: @Roland the first paragraph says "supplied arguments [...] are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the calling function." Doesn't that mean `f(as.environment(-1))` and `f(a<-as.environment(-1))` should throw an error here?

Comment: @MikkoMarttila "It is also worth noting ..."

Comment: @Roland thanks yes it's clear the assignment behaves as expected. I'm just saying that the explicitly supplied `as.environment(-1)` should be evaluated in the calling scope and as such should throw the error it does when called directly in the global environment.

Comment: The doc says "It is also worth noting that the effect of foo(x <- y) if the argument is evaluated is to change the value of x in the calling environment and not in the evaluation environment of foo." but It is weird to evaluate in function environment and assign/binding in the global environment, after all, we use  `->` here, not `->>`